# Usage of Pipes in Ruby Loops

Tags: ruby

So, maybe I'm over-complicating something that isn't that hard, but here goes.

In Ruby, there's a method of looping called .each.  I think that this is very cool--but what I'm finding less cool is the amount of stuff written about the pipe that comes after it (or any other do-type loop in Ruby, it would seem).  Sometimes there is a single thing in the pipe:

```
basket.each do |fruit|
    puts "This is a #{fruit}.\n"
end
```

But sometimes, there are two things in this pipe, like so:

```
contacts.each do |name, profession|
    puts "#{name} is a #{profession}.\n"
end
```

So what I'm wondering now, is it possible to have more than two items in that pipe?  Like if I have a huge, big, and ugly multi-dim array?

What if I add things to my pipe and they're not there?  Will it give the value in the pipe nil?  Or will it throw an error?

Again, sorry if this is obvious to long-time Rubyists, but I came from the land of strictly typed variables, and I'm now leaving PHP land, too. :)

**EDIT**

So what if I have something like this:

```
categories = [["Bathroom", "Bathroom Fixtures", "Plumbing"],
                      ["Ceiling Fixtures", "Chandeliers", "Flush Mounts", "Mini Chandeliers", "Semi-Flush Mounts", "Pendants", "Track Lighting", "Mini Pendants", "Directional", "Island/Pool Table", "Recessed Lighting"],
                      ["Outdoor", "Exterior", "Landscape Lighting"],
                      ["Fans", "Fans", "Fan Accessories"],
                      ["Lamps", "Lamps", "Shades"],
                      ["Wall Fixtures", "Sconces", "Foyer/Hall Lanterns"],
                      ["Specialty", "Undercabinet", "Light Bulbs", "Lighting Controls", "Glass", "Specialty Items", "Utility"],
                      ["Home Decor", "Decor/Home Accents", "Furniture"]]
```

Can I loop through it like this?

```
categories.each do |category, subcats|
    puts "The main category is #{category} and the sub categories are: "
    subcats.each do |subcat|
        puts "#{subcat}, "
    end
end
```

Comment: why not try it out in IRB? i'll try to put together a comprehensive answer nevertheless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a simple array, the following things happen:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

arr.each do |x|
  p x
end
1
2
3
4
=> [1,2,3,4]

arr.each do |x,y|
  p x
  p y
end
1
nil
2
nil
3
nil
4
nil
=> [1,2,3,4]
```

so if ruby doesn't know what to put into the block argument, it simply sets it to `nil`. Now consider a nested array:

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

arr.each do |x|
  p x
end
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

arr.each do |x,y|
  p x
  p y
end
1
2
3
4
5
6
=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

In this case, ruby assumes that you want to assign the two elements of the inner arrays to the block variables `x` and `y`. The same thing applies to hashes, where Ruby assigns the key and value to `x` and `y`:

```
hash = {1 => 2, 3 => 4, 5 => 6}

hash.each do |x,y|
  p x
  p y
end
1
2
3
4
5
6
=> {1=>2,3=>4,5=>6}
```

When you don't have enough elements in the nested arrays, the block variables are assigned `nil`, indeed. When there are too many of them, they are simply discarded:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]

arr.each do |x,y|
  p x
  p y
end
1
2
4
5
6
nil
=> [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

pretty straightforward!

**EDIT**:

As for your edited question: no, you cannot apply this 1:1 to Ruby code, you would have to manually apply the splat operator (`*`) to `subcats`. This way, ruby assigns all remaining elements to the 'splatted' block variable:

```
categories.each do |category,*subcats|
    puts "The main category is #{category} and the sub categories are: "
    subcats.each do |subcat|
        puts "#{subcat}, "
    end
end
```

although i would generate a comma-separated list of subcategories like this:

```
categories.each do |category,*subcats|
    puts "The main category is #{category} and the sub categories are: "
    puts subcats.join(', ')
end
```

**EDIT 2**:

Oh, and you would not handle a huge ugly evil multidimensional array by defining a lot of block parameters for its elements. You probably would iterate through it using nested loops as in almost every other language, if only because you never know how many elements it contains.

Answer (score 5):

Lets start with a break down of the `each` method.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a.each do |num|
  puts num
end

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

The `do ... end` portion is called a `block`

This block accepts one parameter (an element in the array)

The way you pass parameters to a block is with `|`'s

If you supply more than one argument to the block:

```
a.each do |num, x|
  puts num
  puts x
end

# 1
# 
# 2
# 
# 3
# 
# 4
# 
# 5 
#
```

`x` is `nil` for each iteration.

Lets write a method of our own that uses blocks so you can see how they work.

```
def my_each(a=[])
  a.each do |x|
    yield x if block_given?
  end
end

my_each(a) do |num|
  puts num
end
```

Here `yield x` is saying, execute the supplied block and pass `x` to it.

If you pass another parameter to your `block`, it is `nil`. Why?

Our implementation of `my_each` doesn't know anything about a second parameter so it does not `yield` anything so it remains `nil`.

Comment: Awesome!  What about my edit that I added--will it behave like coffeescript's splat?

Comment: @belovedofdeath: you should really try out `irb` and simply play around a little bit!

Answer (score 1):

The pipes you are talking about is a parameter list of a block "variable". Actually that is some kind of a function pointer, and the pipes marks the parameter list.

Check the description of [array.each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each).

This is not magic, the number of parameters is defined in the block, you can't add more than that, if you do, they won't get a value. The reason is for "sometime" there can be more than one, is that it's probably a hash.each, which has two parameters, a key and a value.

You can create your own functions with block parameters, [read this](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-ruby-blocks-and-rolling-your-own-iterators/).

For your iteration problem, you can use a hash, or you can write your own iterator.

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple Arguments to a Block

[Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) iterates over an array object, and passes either a single object into the block or returns an enumerator. You can redefine this behavior, but #each is the wrong method if you want multiple values at a time; see [Enumerator#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) for an alternative.

#### Data Structures

Your problem would be easier to solve with the right data structure. Instead of an array, you should consider using a hash. For example:

```
categories = 
  {"Bathroom"=>["Bathroom Fixtures", "Plumbing"],
   "Ceiling Fixtures"=>["Chandeliers", "Flush Mounts", "Mini Chandeliers"]}

categories.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}:"
  value.each { |v| puts "\t%s" % v }
end
```

This returns:

```
Bathroom:
    Bathroom Fixtures
    Plumbing
Ceiling Fixtures:
    Chandeliers
    Flush Mounts
    Mini Chandeliers
```